# Bash script that enters each directory and runs the script in that directory

Tags: unix

I have a bash script that I use for extracting a set of data I need, and it works great when I am in the directory where the initial input file is.

```
#!/bin/bash 
sed -n '/FIRST KEYWORD/,/KEYWORD THAT STOPS SEARCH/p' initial_input.out >  tmp1.dat
sed -n '/SECOND KEYWORD/,/KEYWORD THAT STOPS SEARCH/p' tmp1.dat > tmp2.dat
awk '/parameter name/' spintmp2.dat
```

Effectively, I cut out the part of the file I need with `sed` and then use awk to get the lines associated with "parameter name". The reason I don't do awk right away is because the string "parameter name" is repeated many times in the `initial_input.out` file.

My output might look something like

```
parameter name    25.3  18.0  4.0 
parameter name    4.3   51.3  54.0
parameter name    1.3   1.4   1.5
```

Now I would like to do this for every initial input file in all subdirectories. For example I am in a directory that contains subdirectories named "one", "two", and "three", each containing their own initial input file (which can be represented as *.out).

How can I run this script from my current directory, and receive the output from all subdirectories at once, knowing which output is coming from which subdirectory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps loop over the result of `find`:

```
find . -name "*.out" | while read path; do
    echo "The path is $path"
    # do stuff
done
```